PCA in Python: Reproducing pca.fit_transform() results using pca.fit()?
I have a data frame called data_principal_components with dimensions (306x21154), so 306 observations and 21154 features. Using PCA, I want to project the data into 10 dimensions.
As far as I understand, the following code does this. The resulting matrix (projected) has a dimension of (306x10).
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# Sample data:
# Define the dimensions of the DataFrame
num_rows = 306
num_cols = 21154

# Generate random numbers from a normal distribution
data = np.random.randn(num_rows, num_cols)

# Create a DataFrame from the random data
data_principal_components = pd.DataFrame(data)

pca = PCA(10)  
projected = pca.fit_transform(data_principal_components)
```

To better understand how the code works, I wanted to reproduce the result of pca.fit_transform() manually.
Based on my research, I found the following steps:
pc_components = pca.components_  # This gives the eigenvectors
pc_components = pc_components.transpose()  # Transposes the eigenvectors, so it has the dimensions (21154x10)
eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_  # These are the eigenvalues with dimensions (1x10)

Now, as I understand, one can calculate the loadings using the following code based on the formula $\text{loadings} = \text{eigenvectors} \times \sqrt{\text{eigenvalues}}$ :
# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over eigenvalues
for i in range(len(eigenvalues)):
    result = np.dot(pc_components[:, i], np.sqrt(eigenvalues[i]))
    df[f'Result_{i+1}'] = result  # Assign result as a new column in the DataFrame
    
loadings = df
```

After obtaining the loadings with dimensions (21154x10), I wanted to use them to obtain the projected values with $ \text{Actual values} \times \text{loadings}$ resulting in dimensions (306x21154) $\times$ (21154x10) = (306x10):
test = np.dot(data_principal_components, loadings)

However, when I compare test to projected, the values differ substantially. Where am I wrong?
EDIT
I found this way to extract the loadings. However, I still want to derive them semi-manually, can somone help?:
pca = PCA(10)  # project from 64 to 2 dimensions
projected = pca.fit_transform(data_principal_components)

loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_.T, columns=['PC1', 'PC2','PC3', 'PC4','PC5', 'PC6','PC7', 'PC8','PC9', 'PC10'], index=data_principal_components.columns)
loadings


components_ must be applied to the centered form of your data to match what scikit is giving you. Also, it's better to work with smaller dimensions and plain numpy arrays for the sake of clarity when figuring things out. Pandas seem to added unnecessary noise IMO.

Okay, yes the data_principal_components is already centered and scaled to zero mean and variance of 1, but still I dont get the same results.

maybe check source code for PCA.fit_transform

Don't scale the data. Just remove the mean and multiply it by the components_.

You ask for two different things here:

I wanted to reproduce the result of pca.fit_transform()

When you ask about the result of pca.fit_transform(), you're asking about the principal component (PC) scores.

I found this way to extract the loadings. However, I still want to
derive them semi-manually, can somone help?

Here you ask about the loadings.
In a nutshell, using singular value decomposition, you can decompose your data matrix as X = USV.T where

U -> normalized PC scores
S -> singular values which are directly linked to the eigenvalues
V -> eigenvectors (often called loadings)

So this allows you to answer your second question: You obtain the loadings by applying a SVD to your data matrix:
data = data - data.mean(0)  # don't forget to center your data
U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(data)
loadings = VT.T  # your loadings

Now, the result of pca.fit_transform() is just the projection of your centered data onto these loadings:
PC_scores = xr.dot(data, loadings[:, :10)  # use the first 10 components only

